Is there any flag to stop langgraph for further executing?
I want to create a interviewing bot that may ask 5 questions. The questions are specified in the system prompt. I just want the langgraph to stop execution when 5 certain questions are asked.
I tried quick start of the langgraph official docs. I read the documentation and I found human-in-the-loop concept but I don't want that. I want the langgraph to completely quits once user answers the questions correctly. If user does not answer correctly, langgraph should ask the question again. I have done that. There might be more attempts of user input than the total questions if user answers incorrectly. I expect that once user answers the questions correclty, langgraph must exist so that user can not exploit the resources.
